# Move FileNet 5.1 content to different FileStore

Tags: filenet-p8

I am looking for a way to move content based on a create_date range to a different FileStore within the same object store. I've been told that this is possible using FEM but I am not familiar with writing VBScript or Java code.

Comment: Any possibility of upgrading to 5.2.1? There's a new feature called [sweeps](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc184.htm?cp=SSNW2F_5.2.0%2F5-4-2-3-0-2), that does what you want much easier than in previous versions.

Comment: Currently our client does not have a plan to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

From 5.2 CPE add new features Sweeps Jobs - it's scheduled tasks, in this tasks it's easy to create policy based jobs to move content from one SA to another.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc184.htm?cp=SSNW2F_5.2.0%2F5-4-2-3-0-2

May be it will be chippests solution.

In 5.1 you have to use VBScript or JS or you can create simple application in Java or .NET.

Answer (score 0):

For anything below 5.2 (like version 5.1 and 4.5) as stated by [@swepss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28761329/1747983) you would need to use API [**moveContent**](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_4.5.1/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/content_engine_api/javadocs/com/filenet/api/action/MoveContent.html)

[Here some examples by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_4.5.1/com.ibm.p8.doc/developer_help/content_engine_api/guide/document_procedures.htm#doc_procedures_move_content)